# How to access excel 2010 sheet from an external tool?

Tags: vba, perl, excel, excel-2010

I have an excel 2010 workbook.
I would like to extract a specific sheet (by name) from it and save it as csv file.

The main requirement is doing so from an external program (program language is not critical.. i can use perl/python/vb, whatever works...)

I browsed the web (google it) but couldn't find any documentation how to do it.

I did find that excel 2010 is actually a zip, but looking into it, i couldn't find the sheets' names....

Did anyone have any experience in such tasks?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @dgw: i defintaly know the purpose of Stack Overflow... but... i think i actually described the problem... i can't access the sheet by name as the excel 2010 as zip, doesn't list them...'

Comment: Then add what you have already tried to the question. Right now it reads like a give-me-the-code question. Add your code, what you have already achieved and where you are stuck, then you'll get answers. Otherwise your question is very likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged the question with `perl`.  So, you can definitely solve the problem using perl, just install few already developed perl-modules from the CPAN repository. Check http://metacpan.org .

It is easy task to google them, but if you're unable find the needed ones, here are:

- [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) - the basic module for reading Excel files using perl. You need to be familiar with this one - you will learn the basic "logic" how to deal with workbook, sheets, cells and so on.
- [Spreadsheet::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::XLSX) - Like the above, but could read the 2007+ `XLSX` file-type. (Your case).

Using the above modules you will be able read your `XLSX` files. For the second part, (saving it as `csv`) - again exists already developed and well-tested modules, like:

- [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) - Text::CSV_XS provides facilities for the composition and decomposition of comma-separated values.

Usually the real-world perl-script for such simple problem (using the above modules) is only few (10-15) lines long.

But, if you want deal with edge cases, for example character encoding conversion and like - maybe you will need to use few other modules too.